# SQLAlchemy/SQL help for Pyramid-style permission filtering of hierarchical ACLs

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm working on a repo for traversal in SQL. I'm hoping to document, tutorial-style, the best way to do it. And hopefully, provide a Pyramid add-on library to give people a starting point. Hence 
https://github.com/pauleveritt/pyramid_sqltraversal -- it has 6 Sphinx-docs sections.

But I'm going to have some hard, weird SQLAlchemy questions. Right now I'm working on permission-filtering in standard SQLAlchemy queries. I've made the commitment that this is only for PostgreSQL 9.4+, so I'll use JSONB to store the ACL. I don't want each row's ACL to be evaluated in Python, as it could mean tens of thousands of queries in a request. So I need some SQL to pick apart the ACEs in an ACL.

Here's my writeup of the strategy: https://github.com/pauleveritt/pyramid_sqltraversal/blob/master/docs/filtered_queries/index.rst

Here's my placeholder code for the expression in a hybrid method:

https://github.com/pauleveritt/pyramid_sqltraversal/blob/master/docs/filtered_queries/mysite/models/node.py#L115

Just below that is an example of using it. My first questions:

- Is a hybrid method expression an appropriate approach?
- Does sqlalchemy.sql have any constructs for picking apart a sequence, and if so, what would it look like?

I need to match on an ACE in an ACL if any item in the passed-in principals is in the ACLs principals, and if the passed-in permission matches the ACLs permission. Bonus for immediately bailing when the first ACE is matched.

Later I'll ask questions about combining this with a recursive CTE for hierarchies, passing in model/class-based ACLs into the generated SQL, etc.

Comment: Instinctively, I think you need PL/pgSQL if you really want DB-side processing. But it all depends on the actual nature of your principals, permissions, and ACLs. Do you have more concrete examples?

Comment: Here's what an ACL looks like:

https://github.com/pauleveritt/pyramid_sqltraversal/blob/master/docs/filtered_queries/mysite/scripts/initialize_db.py#L42

acl1 = [(Allow, Everyone, 'view'), ]

Comment: I didn't put together a solution because I don't know your permissions inheritance model. But I would start by maintaining a closure table that then allows resolution of specific resource ACLs based on ancestor ACLs. If you cache the lookup table, then ACL lookups are fast, obv.